# ASP.Net Web API can't seem to find the correct method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a new object, and trying to POST it to my Web API service to save to the database.

I pass it over this way:

```
private RestClient<Profile> profileClient = new RestClient<Profile>(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"],
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true);
///...
var postResult = profileClient.PostRequest("api/Profile", newProfile).Result;
```

The service's ProfileController method I'm trying to get is this:

```
[SecretAuthenticationFilter(SharedSecretName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", HmacSecret = true)]      
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{

    //....

    [HttpGet]
    public IList<Profile> GetProfile()//IHttpActionResult GetProfile()//
    {
        var returnContent = _profileservices.GetAll();//Ok(_profileservices.GetAll());//
        return returnContent;
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Profile))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProfile(Guid id)
    {
        Profile Profile = _profileservices.Get(id);
        if (Profile == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(Profile);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Profile))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProfile(Profile Profile)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        GuidValue = Guid.NewGuid(); //CreateGuid();

        Resource res = new Resource();
        res.ResourceId = GuidValue;
        var data23 = Resourceservices.Insert(res);

        Profile.ProfileId = data23.ResourceId;
        _profileservices.Insert(Profile);

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Profile.ProfileId }, Profile);
    }
}
```

The routing is:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

My message is:

> {"Message":"Error validating request to Services:Profile:PostProfile"}

GET calls to the web service work.

Comment: Looks like the filter (SecretAuthenticationFilter) is failing, not the URL

Comment: The Get and Post use the same constructor for creating the RestClient. I don't know if it's that. Could it be anything else? or could there be something I can check to see if it is the authentication filter?